# Willingness to Accept categorial or continuous variable?

Tags: ordinal-data, continuous-data

I've asked my participants to enter their "willingness to accept" in dollars. Now I am wondering whether this variable should be treated as an ordinal variable or categorial variable? Unfortunately there are contradictory statements in the papers. 
Thank you so much!

Comment: This is unclear without the context of of what they are accepting.  Is increasing in dollars better or worse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title differs from your text. Your title asks "ordinal or continuous", your text says "ordinal or categorical". Ordinal variables are one type of categorical variable; that is, they take on only a certain number of possible values.

I'm not sure how "willingness to accept" can be measured in dollars. However if they could fill in any number, then it's at least potentially so close to continuous that it doesn't matter.  Money is a ratio level variable.

However, depending on the exact question and also on how the people filled it out, it might make sense to treat it as ordinal. And if you treat it as continuous, it might make sense to take the log.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you for your quick response. 
As my participants were allowed to fill in any number, I will treat this variable as continuous.

Comment: Thanks. If my answer was helpful, the usual thing to do is upvote it. If it is a solution, you can also accept it.